# How to authenticate a Django session using captcha?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, captcha, django-authentication

I have built a website, and a captcha. The captcha is generated by models and displayed on a template.

**Views**

```
from resumesite.models import Chess_board
import json

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def chess(request):
    board = Chess_board()
    data = mark_safe(json.dumps(board.rep))
    return render(request, 'captcha_original.html',{'board': data})
```

I would like to redirect all requests to the captcha, and on completion of the captcha redirect to website and allow full access for duration of the session (i.e. for period of 20 minutes). How would you suggest going about this?

**Options**

1. Middleware/decorator authenticating by ip address (I have read this won't work if user is using a proxy)
2. Custom login form, with decorator `@login_required(login_url="/chess/")`
3. Integrating with REST and using token authentication

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a server-side session to handle the access. By using the server-side session you can set an expiry. In the session store, a variable called access=True, which you can check in the other function if it exists and serve pages. After the expiry time hits, this session is deleted and function will see a None value.
For more information read following docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine

Comment: But, how would you get the javascript or html to change your access variable?